# Run the main python program from any sub-program file

Tags: python, import

This is more of a convenience than a real problem, but the project I'm working on has a lot of separate files, and I want to basically be able to run any of those files (that all basically only contain classes) to run the main file.

Now in the middle of writing the first sentence of this question, I tried just importing `main.py` into each file, and that seemed to work fine and dandy, but I cant help but feeling that:

1. it might cause problems, and
2. that I had problems with circular imports before and I am somewhat surprised that nothing came up.

Comment: Why do you think you need this? Having a single command-line entry point to a program makes it much simpler for both you and the user.

Comment: like i said, its more of a convenience for me when programming. It's much faster to just do a quick f5-enter, than to save the file, and find the main.py tab and run it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let me say: this is most likely a bad idea, and it's definitely not at all standard. It will likely lead to confusion and frustration down the road.

However, if you really want to do it, you can put:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from mypackage import main
    main.run()
```

Which, assuming `mypackage.main.run()` is your main entry point, will let you run any file you want as if it were the main file.

You may still hit issues issues with circular imports, and those will be completely unavoidable, unless `mypackage.main` doesn't import anything… Which would make it fairly useless :)

Comment: Alrighty, I knew it was working how i wanted it to, but I would rather save myself annoyance later than save a little bit of time and if you think its a bad idea XD.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you may wish to use a testing framework like [doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) or [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html), then configure your IDE to run the unit tests from a hotkey.  This way you're automatically building the repeatable tests as you develop your code.